# compare age with birthdate in where clause

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-expressions

how to compare age with birthdate in where clause? Somthing like this code:

```
myRepository.Where(x =>
    fromAge <= x.BirthDate.Age && x.BirthDate.Age <= toAge)
    .Select(x).toList();
```

Data Types:

fromAge, toAge : int

x.BirthDate: DateTime

Comment: What's wrong with your code?

Comment: x.BirthDate.Age is fake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

after searching, i ended up with this solution:

```
toDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-fromAge).Date.AddYears(1).AddDays(-1);
fromDate = DateTime.Now.AddYears(-toAge).Date.AddYears(-1).AddDays(+1);
```

consider changing "fromAge" to "toDate" and "toAge" to "fromDate". so:

```
myRepository.Where(x => fromDate <= x.BirthDate && x.BirthDate <= toDate)
    .Select(x).toList();
```

Answer (score 0):

I presume `x.BirthDate` is a DateTime.

You can get a person's age given a DateTime representing their D.O.B. like so:

```
double age = Math.Floor(DateTime.Now.Subtract(BirthDate).TotalDays / 365.25m);
```

You can make this into an extension method:

```
public static int Age(this DateTime birthDate)
{
    return (int)Math.Floor(DateTime.Now.Subtract(birthDate).TotalDays / 365.25m);
}
```

And then you can do:

```
myRepository.Where(x => fromAge <= x.BirthDate.Age() && x.BirthDate.Age() <= toAge).ToList();
```

Be advised however, if `myRepository` is an EntityFramework `DbSet`, this will not work. You will have to do `myRepository.AsEnumerable().Where(// etc)`, otherwise you will get an exception.

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Age(System.DateTime)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @AliDehqan I explained how to avoid that in the last line of my answer.

Comment: you're getting all data from repository with AsEnumerable() and then using where. which is not the correct way

Comment: @AliDehquan There is no "correct" way. There are many different ways, each with its own pros and cons. The one I have provided works perfectly, and will only cause problems if you're dealing with extremely large amounts of data (millions of rows).

Answer (score 0):

Construct a WHERE clause in the following way

```
myRepository.Where(x =>
        fromAge <= (Datetime.Now.Year - x.BirthDate.Year) && (Datetime.Now.Year - x.BirthDate.Year) <= toAge)
        .Select(x).toList();
```

Comment: that's not the correct way of computing age.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming fromAge and toAge are years:

`myRepository.Where(x => DateTime.Now.AddYears(-fromAge) <= x.BirthDate && x.BirthDate <= DateTime.Now.AddYears(-toAge)).ToList();`

Comment: that's not the correct way of computing age.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to add this to your BirthDate class:

```
[NotMapped]
public int Age { 
    get {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        int age = now.Year - BirthDate.Year;
        if(now < BirthDate.AddYears(age)) age--;
        return age;
        }
   }
```

this is make your age property for auto calculate from birthdate

Comment: your function is correct, but we can not use Age method in query expression.

Comment: myRepository.Where(x =>
    fromAge <= x.BirthDate.Age).Where(x.BirthDate.Age <= toAge)
    .Select(x).toList();

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 Age(System.DateTime)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: you have to create a [NotMapped] property next to the BirthDate property called Age like mine